# Image uploading - How to get the right format of image data for server side processing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, dropzone.js

I'm using [sharp](http://sharp.dimens.io/en/stable/api/) to process images on the server side and [react dropzone](https://github.com/okonet/react-dropzone) to get the image file. When I post the file to the server from dropzone, I get the blob out of the request.body that looks like:

`{ preview: 'blob:http%3A//127.0.0.1%3A3000/1451580a-b24f-478f-a9f7-338c0d790829' }`

Optionally, before I send data to the server I can use FileReader (or something else) to do something with the image file instead of turning it into a blob.

Sharp takes:

- A Buffer containing JPEG, PNG, WebP, GIF, SVG, TIFF
- Raw pixel image data
- A String containing the path to an image file, with most major formats supported.

How can I use what I have to provide sharp a supported format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend trying out a node.js module called Multer to help you access your photo file on your server.

https://github.com/expressjs/multer

First, on the client, you'll want to append your file to a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object like this:

```
// obtain the file from your react dropzone and save it to this file variable
const file = dropzone.file // not sure how you do this with react dropzone
const data = new FormData()
data.append('photo', file)
```

Then you'll send this FormData object to your server. On the server you'll use Multer on the route you're using for the photo for processing.

Make sure you npm install multer, and require it on your server or routes file. If you're sending a single file you'll use the multer 'single' method. If you want to do anything different check out the API documentation.

```
app.post('/photos', multer().single('photo'), controller.processPhoto);
```

In this example route, you're sending a POST request to /photos, multer is looking for a file with a FormData key of 'photo' and appending that to the request object.

Then in this made up 'controller.processPhoto' method you'll have access to the image as a property of the request object, on `req.file`. With this you can easily access a lot of good information including the image buffer `req.file.buffer` which it sounds like you need. (also mimetype, original name etc.)

This should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly! `const data = new FormData()` combined with multer was the key. I didn't know about the FormData object.

Comment: @MikeJonas did you use `file.preview` as the variable to pass to `data.append` ?